# Display SQL data in TreeView

Tags: vb.net

I am showing data from 1 table from SQL Server 2018 to a TreeView. I can only show the tree up to this point

```
Private Sub btnPopular_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPopular.Click

    Dim conexaoSQLServer As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    'DBSQLServer = "SELECT RTRIM(D.DESCRIPCION),RTRIM(P.DESCRIPCION) " +
    '"FROM PROVINCIAS AS P INNER JOIN DEPARTAMENTO AS D ON P.IDDEPARTAMENTO=D.IDDEPARTAMENTO"

    Dim strCon As String = "Data Source = SOPORTE-ERP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = prueba; Integrated Security = True"

    'define a consulta para obter as tabelas e suas colunas
    Dim sqlConsulta As String = "SELECT RTRIM(D.DESCRIPCION),RTRIM(P.DESCRIPCION) " +
                                "FROM PROVINCIA AS P INNER JOIN DEPARTAMENTO AS D ON P.IDDEPARTAMENTO=D.IDDEPARTAMENTO"
    'define os nodes que iremos usar no treeview
    Dim NoRaiz As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim NoPrincipal As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim NoFilho As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim nieto As TreeNode = Nothing
    'define algumas constanes e variaveis usadas
    Dim nomePrincipal As String = String.Empty
    Dim nomeFilho As String = String.Empty

    Dim BancoDados As String = DBSQLServer

    Try
        'define e abre a conexão com o SQL Server
        conexaoSQLServer = New SqlConnection(strCon)
        conexaoSQLServer.Open()

        'atribui o comando usado na conexão
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlConsulta, conexaoSQLServer)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        'preenche o dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "DATOS_SISTEMAS")

        tvwDados.Nodes.Clear()
        'inclui o node raiz
        NoRaiz = tvwDados.Nodes.Add("UBIGEO")

        Dim contaTabelas As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("DATOS_SISTEMAS").Rows

            If nomePrincipal <> row(0).ToString Then
                NoPrincipal = NoRaiz.Nodes.Add(row(0).ToString)
                'imageIndex:=1, selectedImageIndex:=1'
                nomePrincipal = row(0).ToString
                contaTabelas += 1
            End If

            NoFilho = NoPrincipal.Nodes.Add(key:="", text:=row(1).ToString)
            'nieto = NoPrincipal.Nodes.Add(key:="DISTRITOS", text:=row(2).ToString)
            'imageIndex:=2, selectedImageIndex:=2

        Next

        lblTabelas.Text = contaTabelas.ToString & " Tabelas no arquivo"

        tvwDados.Nodes(0).EnsureVisible()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao realizar a operação com o arquivo : " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    Finally
        'libera os recursos da conexão usada
        conexaoSQLServer.Close()
        conexaoSQLServer.Dispose()
        conexaoSQLServer = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

And it shows me as follows in the picture

[image: muestra imagen]

now I want another sub-tree or item to be broken down to me where the districts are shown as follows DEPARTMENT / PROVINCE / DISTRICT

[image: How I want to display it]

Comment: vba <> vb.net and vba is not used in visual studios.  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, this is a data querying question.

I use these conceptual tables for my answer. I hope they reflect your actual table structure.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO (
  IDDEPARTAMENTO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTAMENTO PRIMARY KEY (IDDEPARTAMENTO),
  CONSTRAINT UQ_DEPARTAMENTO UNIQUE (DESCRIPCION)
);

CREATE TABLE PROVINCIA (
  IDDEPARTAMENTO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  IDPROVINCIA CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_PROVINCIA PRIMARY KEY (IDDEPARTAMENTO, IDPROVINCIA),
  CONSTRAINT UQ_PROVINCIA UNIQUE (IDDEPARTAMENTO, DESCRIPCION),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PROVINCIA_DEPARTAMENTO FOREIGN KEY (IDDEPARTAMENTO) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO (IDDEPARTAMENTO)
);

CREATE TABLE UBIGEO (
  IDUBIGEO CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  IDDEPARTAMENTO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  IDPROVINCIA CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_UBIGEO PRIMARY KEY (IDUBIGEO),
  CONSTRAINT UQ_UBIGEO UNIQUE (IDDEPARTAMENTO, IDPROVINCIA, DESCRIPCION),
  CONSTRAINT FK_UBIGEO_PROVINCIA FOREIGN KEY (IDDEPARTAMENTO, IDPROVINCIA) REFERENCES PROVINCIA (IDDEPARTAMENTO, IDPROVINCIA)
);
```

Next, I would look at the data that is actually required for populating a treeview. Every node refers to a parent node (or a parent node contains several child nodes). I would like to reflect that in the data that I retrieve from the database.

Each of the above three tables holds node data. Instead of using `JOIN`s, I would use `UNION`s here, so that each row in the result data represents a single node. Each row should contain at least three fields:

- `nodeText` will contain the node text that is displayed in the treeview's nodes
- `nodeKey` will contain a unique textual key for the node
- `nodeParentKey` will contain the key of the parent node (or an empty string if it has no parent)

So the query that I would execute to retrieve the node data would look something like this:

```vb
'define a consulta para obter as tabelas e suas colunas
Dim sqlConsulta As String = "
SELECT
  D.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,
  'DEPA' + D.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS nodeKey,
  '' AS nodeParentKey
FROM
  DEPARTAMENTO AS D
UNION ALL
SELECT
  P.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,
  'PROV' + P.IDDEPARTAMENTO + P.IDPROVINCIA AS nodeKey,
  'DEPA' + P.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS nodeParentKey
FROM
  PROVINCIA AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT
  U.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,
  'DIST' + U.IDUBIGEO AS nodeKey,
  'PROV' + U.IDDEPARTAMENTO + U.IDPROVINCIA AS nodeParentKey
FROM
  UBIGEO AS U
"
```

I would rewrite the loop that processes your retrieved data and actually convert it to two loops.

The first loop processes the retrieved data and creates the `TreeNode` objects. But instead of immediately putting them in a `Nodes` collection in the `tvwDados` treeview, I would put them in a helper dictionary. Additionally, I would store the node's key in another helper dictionary as well. These helper dictionaries will be used in the second loop.

The second loop actually populates the `tvwDados` treeview from the `nodes` dictionary and add the node either to the `tvwDados.Nodes` collection or a parent node's `Nodes` collection, which depends if a parent key can be found in the `nodeParents` dictionary.

My data processing code would look something like this:

```vb
'Helper dictionaries
Dim nodes As New Dictionary(Of String, TreeNode) 'Holds the nodes based on their key values
Dim nodeParents As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'Holds the parent keys of child nodes

'Create nodes from data
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("DATOS_SISTEMAS").Rows
  Dim nodeText As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeText")
  Dim nodeKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeKey")
  Dim nodeParentKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeParentKey")

  nodes.Add(nodeKey, New TreeNode(nodeText))

  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeParentKey) Then
    nodeParents.Add(nodeKey, nodeParentKey)
  End If
Next

'Add nodes to treeview (and resolve parents)
For Each kvp In nodes
  Dim node As TreeNode = kvp.Value
  Dim nodeKey As String = kvp.Key
  Dim nodeParentKey As String = Nothing

  If nodeParents.TryGetValue(nodeKey, nodeParentKey) Then
    'Child node
    Dim parentNode As TreeNode = nodes(nodeParentKey)
    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node)
  Else
    'Root node
    tvwDados.Nodes.Add(node)
  End If
Next
```

I am not sure about the purpose of your `contraTabelas` integer and your `NoRaiz`, `NoPrincipal` and `NoFilho` tree nodes. For the sake of clarity I omitted them from my code. I assume that you will be able to include them in the processing logic yourself if you still need them.

**Edit:**

If you want to do special things when double clicking a district node, you can pass additional data in a node's `Tag` property.

In the above code, change this line:

```vb
nodes.Add(nodeKey, New TreeNode(nodeText))
```

to this:

```vb
Dim node As New TreeNode(nodeText)
node.Tag = nodeKey
nodes.Add(nodeKey, node)
```

Next, you can implement the tree view's `NodeMouseDoubleClick` event handler. It could look something like this:

```vb
Private Sub tvwDados_NodeMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles tvwDados.NodeMouseDoubleClick
  Dim nodeKey As String = TryCast(e.Node.Tag, String)

  If nodeKey IsNot Nothing AndAlso nodeKey.StartsWith("DIST") Then
    'You have double clicked a district node
    Dim IDDISTRITO As Integer = Integer.Parse(nodeKey.Substring(4))

    'Do something with the district id here
    '...
  End If
End Sub
```

If you need help with additional subjects, just feel free to post an entirely new question here on StackOverflow.

**Edit:**

I have updated my answer based on new information. I have made changes to the conceptual table structure and the SQL query in the `sqlConsulta` variable. As far as I can determine, it should not produce duplicate key errors anymore.

I think that the duplicate key errors came from the province nodes. So for the province nodes, I included both the department ID and the province ID in the node key.

Comment: friend shows me an error message when executing the published code, I have published the error that shows me

Comment: PERFECT ALREADY SHOWING, DEPARTMENT / PROVINCE / DISTRICT
I HAVE ANOTHER QUERY HOW TO PASS THE SELECTED DATA TO 1 TEXT BOX, INCLUDING THE DISTRICT ID, THIS IS THE EVENT TreeView1_DoubleClick

Comment: Ah. Yes. Adding additional data to a tree node can be easy. A tree node has a `Tag` property of type `Object`. You are free to use that property as you like. You can put any custom data (like the `nodeKey` value for example) in a node's `Tag` property when you populate the tree view. If you implement the tree view's `NodeMouseDoubleClick` event, the event handler's `e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs` parameter has a `Node` property that holds the `TreeNode` object that you have double clicked, so you can very easily access the node's `Tag` property there. I will edit my answer.

Comment: MY FRIEND THANKS FOR YOUR HELP EVERYTHING WORKED WELL, UNTIL I LINK IT TO A TABLE THAT HAS THE COMPLETE RECORDS AND SHOWS ME THE MESSAGE "I ALREADY ADD AN ITEM WITH THE SAME KEY" AND THE ERROR IS NOT WHERE TO BE IF THE WANT IS THE SAME AND THE SAME CODE

Comment: Very strange. With this SQL query, you should get unique `nodeKey` values, so there should be no duplicate key error when you add nodes to the `nodes` dictionary in the first loop. Do your database tables happen to contain duplicate IDs? The following query should not yield any results: `SELECT 'DEPA' AS TBL, IDDEPARTAMENTO AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM DEPARTAMENTO GROUP BY IDDEPARTAMENTO UNION ALL SELECT 'PROV' AS TBL, IDPROVINCIA AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM PROVINCIA GROUP BY IDPROVINCIA UNION ALL SELECT 'DIST' AS TBL, IDUBIGEO AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM ubigeo GROUP BY IDUBIGEO`

Comment: Hello friend thanks for answering, this new table of ubigeo is the same structure, the only difference is that this table contains the complete information are 24 unique departments, its fields IDUBIGEO or IDDISTRITO are unique and autoincrementable, execute the query and it shows me these values

Comment: TBL = DST , ID = 1, CNT = 1,  -----------AND SO SUCCESSIVELY, NO DATA IS REPEATED, I CAN THINK THAT THIS BECAUSE OF THE CODE IN VB, BUT WELL RARE.

Comment: OK... Still strange. I forgot HAVING clauses in my earlier query. All CNT column values in my earlier query should be 1. Below is the query I intended. It should return nothing, since it should only show rows with CNT > 1: `SELECT 'DEPA' AS TBL, IDDEPARTAMENTO AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM DEPARTAMENTO GROUP BY IDDEPARTAMENTO HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'PROV' AS TBL, IDPROVINCIA AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM PROVINCIA GROUP BY IDPROVINCIA HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'DIST' AS TBL, IDUBIGEO AS ID, COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM ubigeo GROUP BY IDUBIGEO HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Hello, I executed the code, pointing to this new database and it shows me I believe duplicate data, how can I avoid this duplicate data in the executed query?

Comment: If the query in your `sqlConsulta` variable really returns duplicate keys when connected to a new database, please execute the testquery in my earlier comment (the one with the HAVING clauses) on that new database. You can use SQL Server Management Studio to execute it. In case of duplicate keys in your database tables, the testquery will return more information about those duplicates and then you should probably **change those duplicate keys/IDs in your database tables**. If there are no duplicates in your tables, then the testquery will return nothing and your code should run successfully.

Comment: Could it be the case, for example, that you have two (or more) districts with the same `IDUBIGEO` key value, but in different provinces (with different `IDPROVINCIA` values)!?

Comment: That's right, friend, it has two or more districts but in different provinces, I don't think it would be duplicated?.
I post what it shows me.

Comment: OK... So the `IDUBIGEO` value is NOT unique as I assumed in my answer. In that case, the node's key values should be determined somewhat differently...

Comment: How about provinces? Can there be provinces with the same `IDPROVINCIA` key value, but within different departments (different IDDEPARTAMENTO values)?

Comment: not each, province is unique in each department, the districts if they can vary the nomenclature in my country is the following unique department / unique province / district are unique in a particular case it is repeated in another province but in this database I do not understand why I I get the error message.

Comment: Hmmm. So... district IDs are not necessarily unique per province?

Comment: They are the only ones already validated that question, below publish how the ubigeo or district table is made up, I see that the error could be in the code I am debugging to find the fault, to see if you can support me with that point.

Answer (score 0):

the structure of my database is the same as what you are proposing, executing the query with a small change shows me as follows.

```
SELECT D.DESCRIPCION AS nodetext,CAST(D.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,'' AS nodeParentKey
FROM DEPARTAMENTO AS D UNION ALL
SELECT P.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,CAST(P.IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,CAST(P.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey
FROM PROVINCIA AS P UNION ALL
SELECT U.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,CAST(U.IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,CAST(U.IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey
FROM ubigeo AS U SELECT * FROM ubigeo
```

**UBIGEO IS A DISTRICT**

AND IT SHOWS SO

[image]

when executing the code that you published it shows me this error message

```html
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conexaoSQLServer As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        DBSQLServer = "prueba"

        Dim strCon As String = "Data Source = DESKTOP-2IM88ST\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = " & DBSQLServer & "; Integrated Security = True"

        'define a consulta para obter as tabelas e suas colunas
        Dim sqlConsulta As String = "SELECT D.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,CAST(D.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,'' AS nodeParentKey FROM DEPARTAMENTO AS D UNION ALL " +
"SELECT P.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,CAST(P.IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,CAST(P.IDDEPARTAMENTO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM PROVINCIA AS P UNION ALL " +
"SELECT U.DESCRIPCION AS nodeText,CAST(U.IDUBIGEO AS VARCHAR) AS nodeKey,CAST(U.IDPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR) AS nodeParentKey FROM ubigeo AS U"


        Try
            'define e abre a conexão com o SQL Server
            conexaoSQLServer = New SqlConnection(strCon)
            conexaoSQLServer.Open()

            'atribui o comando usado na conexão
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlConsulta, conexaoSQLServer)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd

            'preenche o dataset
            da.Fill(ds, "DATOS_SISTEMAS")

            'Helper dictionaries
            Dim nodes As New Dictionary(Of String, TreeNode) 'Holds the nodes based on their key values
            Dim nodeParents As New Dictionary(Of String, String) 'Holds the parent keys of child nodes

            'Create nodes from data
            TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("DATOS_SISTEMAS").Rows
                Dim nodeText As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeText")
                Dim nodeKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeKey")
                Dim nodeParentKey As String = row.Field(Of String)("nodeParentKey")

                nodes.Add(nodeKey, New TreeNode(nodeText))

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeParentKey) Then
                    nodeParents.Add(nodeKey, nodeParentKey)
                End If
            Next

            'Add nodes to treeview (and resolve parents)
            For Each kvp In nodes
                Dim node As TreeNode = kvp.Value
                Dim nodeKey As String = kvp.Key
                Dim nodeParentKey As String = Nothing

                If nodeParents.TryGetValue(nodeKey, nodeParentKey) Then
                    'Child node
                    Dim parentNode As TreeNode = nodes(nodeParentKey)
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node)
                Else
                    'Root node
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao realizar a operação com o arquivo : " & ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            'libera os recursos da conexão usada
            conexaoSQLServer.Close()
            conexaoSQLServer.Dispose()
            conexaoSQLServer = Nothing
        End Try


    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

**error when performing this operation: an element with the same key has already been added**

Comment: You have removed the prefixes from the key field values. I added prefixes `DEPA`, `PROV` and `DIST` before the casted ID values, because the three tables will have rows with equal IDs. You need to differentiate between keys `123` and `123` from tables `DEPARTAMENTO` and `DISTRITO`, for example. Therefore I added prefix, so that the key values would become `DEPA123` and `DIST123` respectively in such a case.

Comment: PERFECT ALREADY SHOWING, DEPARTMENT / PROVINCE / DISTRICT
I HAVE ANOTHER QUERY HOW TO PASS THE SELECTED DATA TO 1 TEXT BOX, INCLUDING THE DISTRICT ID, THIS IS THE EVENT TreeView1_DoubleClick

Answer (score 0):

Bart Hofland,
the query to verify, it shows me this information in the new database.
[image]

**this is the ubigeo or district table**

[image]

Comment: Wow. Yes. Now I see. So you have 25 provinces with `IDPROVINCIA = '01'`. I assume you start at `'01'` for every different department? So for provinces, the combination of `IDDEPARTAMENTO` and `IDPROVINCIA` should be unique? And for districts, the combination of `IDDEPARTAMENTO`, `IDPROVINCIA` and `IDUBIGEO` should be unique?

Comment: So the ID fields are unique and they are self-incrementing apart from the fact that these records are already established and nothing new is entered unless a name is updated but it is rare.

Comment: publish the table UBIGEO or district that could be happening with the error is by sql or by visual?

Comment: I see. I have also taken a quick peek on Wikipedia. Looking at your table, `IDUBIGEO` is already a combination of the region (department), province, and district IDs. Shouldn't the province IDs be `0101`, `0102`, `0103`, and so on?

Comment: no, as you say the Ubigeo is the combination, here they establish it as I show in the uploaded photo, but if you notice even the IDUBIGEO does not repeat itself, then I go to the dictionary side in the vb.net code apparently this getting a duplicate in your sequence, but how do I replace that or fix it?

Comment: OK. I will update my answer based on this new information you have provided. I will update both the conceptual table structure and the `sqlConsulta` query. Please let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: ok, I thank you very much, for your time, this is new for me so I am getting information from anywhere this is a great experience thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. However, next time, try to keep your questions on StackOverflow focused on a single issue as much as possible. Furthermore, StackOverflow works very differently compared to a forum, so if you need to add additional information to your question, you should not post your own answers anymore (unless they solve your issue, of course). Instead, you can always edit your own question and simply append the new info to it. Doing so will keep your questions a lot cleaner, so that in the future, other people might also profit from the information in your question and the provided answers.

Comment: Hello friend, I can update your answer, sorry I asked you since I am also trying to solve and I still have not reached the solution.

Comment: Have you seen [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905802/4174789) yet? I updated the SQL query in the `sqlConsulta` variable. I fixed the `nodeKey` values for the province nodes (and of course the corresponding `nodeParentKey` values for the district nodes as well), so that those keys will not only include `IDPROVINCIA`, but a combination of `IDDEPARTAMENTO` and `IDPROVINCIA`. That way, the keys of the province nodes should always be unique now. (Those keys are only used for populating the tree view correctly, so nothing else will be affected by this change.)

Comment: My friend, you saved me and thanks again for sharing your knowledge, I know that I have to improve and this is one more point for my experience, now it no longer shows me the duplicate error, now I see the difference that you applied in the code